# Using Multiple functions inside single api nodejs + mysql(Sequelize)

Tags: mysql, node.js

This is my api:

```
exports.getactivity = function(req, res) {
    console.log('at the complaint is:');
    Main.findAll({
        include: [
            { model: Admin },
            { model: Store }
         ]
    }).then(function(data) {
         res.status(200).json(data)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        res.status(500).json(error)
    });
};
```

I want to get all table data, so i want to use mutliple functions inside single api.
I have four tables

(Mains,
Admins,
Store,
Service)

Here in the above api, I am getting Mains.findAll, but i want to get all the above mentioned table datas.

Comment: You are joining Main with Admin and Store tables. Do you need to all data from all tables, or just Main table with Admin, Store and Service related fields ?

Comment: sir , actualy i need  activity stream

Comment: you can use promise.all to execute all promises and get result of every function .Read up on it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all